# jsp c:forEach object in list

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

problem in displaying the list of products

Do not display products of class ProductDTO 
my jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>...
```

```
        ...<c:forEach var="ProductDTO" items="${products}" varStatus="loop"></c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${ProductDTO.getDescription()}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${ProductDTO.getName() }"/></td>
        </tr>...
```

Controller

```
    @RequestMapping("/marketplace")
public String marketplace(Model model) {
    if (!userSession.isInLoged())
        return "redirect:login";
    List<ProductDTO> products=productDAO.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("products",products);
    return "marketplace";

}
```

ProductDAO

```
public List<ProductDTO> getAll() {
    String sql = "SELECT* FROM epam_db.products";
    List<ProductDTO> products = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ProductMapper());
    if (products.isEmpty())
        return null;
    return products;
}
```

ProductDTO
package dto;

import java.sql.Date;

```
public class ProductDTO {
    private int idProducts;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Date startDate;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private int users_idusers;
    // getters and setters........
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain more?

Comment: `<td><c:out value="${ProductDTO.getDescription()}"/></td>`
            `<td><c:out value="${ProductDTO.getName() }"/></td>`

does not show in the browser name of product and description
list consists of objects ProductDTO
I want to display the elements of the List<ProductDTO>

Comment: You forgot to describe what exactly happens instead. Symptoms are clues/answers to the problem. Open JSP page in browser, rightclick and do *View Page Source* in order to see its generated HTML output. What exactly do you see there? Do you see `<c:out value="${ProductDTO.getDescription()}"/>` unparsed there? Or is it successfully parsed, but do you see only `${ProductDTO.getDescription()}` unevaluated there? Or is it successfully evaluated and do you see an empty string (nothing) there? Each of those symptoms have their own causes and solutions (which are already asked and answered before)